# Finding the 3rd merchant with the highest lifetime transaction amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to get the 3rd merchant with the highest lifetime
transaction amount. Also, I have to provide the total transactions to date for this
merchant.

This is the create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction(
transaction_id int , user_id int , merchant_name varchar(255), transaction_date date , amount int
);
INSERT INTO transaction(transaction_id, user_id, merchant_name, transaction_date, amount)  
VALUES (1, 1 ,'abc', '2015-01-17', 100),(2, 2, 'ced', '2015-2-17', 100),(3, 1, 'def', '2015-2-16', 120),
(4, 1 ,'ced', '2015-3-17', 110),(5, 1, 'ced', '2015-3-17', 150),(6, 2 ,'abc', '2015-4-17', 130), 
(7, 3 ,'ced', '2015-12-17', 10),(8, 3 ,'abc', '2015-8-17', 100),(9, 2 ,'abc', '2015-12-17', 140),(10, 1,'abc', '2015-7-17', 100),
(11, 1 ,'abc', '2015-01-17', 120),(12, 2 ,'ced', '2015-12-23', 130);
```

I am not sure how the o/p would look like. I am stuck here.

```
SELECT distinct(merchant_name), max(amount) from transaction
```

Comment: What is 'lifetime transaction amount'?  Is that the total `SUM` or the total `COUNT` or the "maximum individual transaction amount" over the lifetime of the merchant's transactions?

Comment: It is the sum of all the transactions done by a merchant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, we could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
transaction_id int , user_id int , merchant_name varchar(255), transaction_date date , amount int
);

INSERT INTO transaction(transaction_id, user_id, merchant_name, transaction_date, amount)  
VALUES (1, 1 ,'abc', '2015-01-17', 100),(2, 2, 'ced', '2015-2-17', 100),(3, 1, 'def', '2015-2-16', 120),
(4, 1 ,'ced', '2015-3-17', 110),(5, 1, 'ced', '2015-3-17', 150),(6, 2 ,'abc', '2015-4-17', 130), 
(7, 3 ,'ced', '2015-12-17', 10),(8, 3 ,'abc', '2015-8-17', 100),(9, 2 ,'abc', '2015-12-17', 140),(10, 1,'abc', '2015-7-17', 100),
(11, 1 ,'abc', '2015-01-17', 120),(12, 2 ,'ced', '2015-12-23', 130)
;

SELECT merchant_name
     , SUM(amount)   AS sum_amount
  FROM transaction
 GROUP BY merchant_name
 ORDER BY sum_amount DESC
 LIMIT 2, 1
;
```

Result:

```
+---------------+------------+
| merchant_name | sum_amount |
+---------------+------------+
| def           |        120 |
+---------------+------------+
```

The full result without limiting, for comparison, is:

```
+---------------+------------+
| merchant_name | sum_amount |
+---------------+------------+
| abc           |        690 |
| ced           |        500 |
| def           |        120 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the meaning of "lifetime transaction", playing with orders and limits, and two levels of aggregation, you can get what you want:

```
select t.merchant_name, count(*)
from transactions t
  join (
      select merchant_name, sum(amount) amount
      from transactions
      group by merchant_name
      order by 2 desc
      limit 3
    ) top3
    on t.merchant_name = top3.merchant_name
group by t.merchant_name    
order by top3.amount asc
limit 1
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b7b31345f1c38759fbde56ca1b88f0e)

If you had a "merchant" dimension, you could get the `merchant_name` from there and perform the `sum` and `count` in the same subquery, improving this way the query performance. Something like this...

```
select m.merchant_name, top3.amount, top3.nbtrans
from merchants m
  join (
      select merchant_name, sum(amount) amount, count(1) as nbtrans
      from transactions
      group by merchant_name
      order by 2 desc
      limit 3
    ) top3
    on t.merchant_name = top3.merchant_name  
order by top3.amount asc
limit 1
```